# Understand call back function in this code

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I see this code in other website but I do not
understand the specific cFunction and url

```js
function loadDoc(url, cFunction) {
  var xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      cFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xhttp) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    xhttp.responseText;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">

  <h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>

  <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc('ajax_info.txt', myFunction)">Change Content</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `url` and `cFunction` are arguments/parameters passed to the `loadDoc` function when it's called.  Are you familiar with functions in JavaScript and how they are structured/called?  If not, you should definitely start with some introductory tutorials on JavaScript.  Being able to create and call a function is a fundamental part of this and many other languages.

Comment: cFunction is a parameter. In your code it contains `myFunction` from the click. In the function it is now known as cFunction and is called using (theXmlHttpObject) in the form of `this` - same as doing `myFunction(this)` or `myFunction(xhttp)`

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted there is a function `loadDoc` that takes as sercond argument another function, the callback `cFunction`.

`loadDoc`, as the name says, loads a document from the internet, identified by the **url** argument, using ajax. When the document is loaded the  **cFunction** function, passed as argument, is called passing the reference of the current **XMLHttpRequest**.

All the stuff loadDoc do, are done when the user clicks on the button, the document that have to be loaded is *ajax_info.txt* and the callback function is **myFunction**

So `myFunction` is called by **loadDoc** when the document is downloaded with the ***XMLHttpRequest*** object that contains the response, as argument, so myFunction can read the response and print it on an HTML element.

In modern browsers you can use [JavaScript debugging tools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp) like console.log and the `debugger` statement